# How to play different hold music in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I have two Asterisk server 'A' and 'B' . In Server 'A', five different ivr (Sevices) is playing and call is forwarding into Server 'B'. Server 'B' basically use for agent login(Extension).
I want to play different hold music(Server 'B') bases on the corresponding services which is running into server 'A'.

A single agent takes the call from different different services but hold music is play astrisk own by default.

Is there any way to   play  different hold music bases on  services which run into server A.

I have some changes into musiconhold.conf (server B) but problem is no solve.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set(CHANNEL(musicclass)=some_class_here)` before music on hold is played